# Non-profit society with 5 hostels: just one FB page or for each their own?

Tags: branch, facebook-page

We are a non-profit society with  a dozen hostels (and other facilities) all over the county.

If we set up a FB page for each hostel our guests could *like* their hostel (the one they associate with because it was their *temporary home*) but they most likely won’t *like* our governing society. This would be cool for the individual hostel to push its reputation but it won’t affect the reputation of our main brand.

Any experience with similar scenarios? What would you do?

Answer (score 0):

Create one page for all of the hostels. It's much easier (and cheaper) to manage and to resell hostels in a different location. Synergy relies in the group not in the individual level.